# How does a customer connect WKC (cloud) to their on-prem data sources?

Tags: watson-knowledge-catalog

Looking for documentation on our overall networking for WKC on Cloud in order to feel confident in its viability & security. Want to know all connectivity and networking options for WKC.

Comment: How much searching online have you already done? For example I found this via Google very quickly: https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/getting-started/welcome-main.html

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way is to use the IBM Cloud Secure Gateway service. WKC has direct support for it.

> - Here are the [docs](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/catalog/c-add-conn.html)
>     for creating a connection.
> - Here are the [docs](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/manage-data/create-conn.html#configure-a-secure-gateway-service)
>     for configuring a secure gateway service.
> - Here are the [docs](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/manage-data/conn_types.html?linkInPage=true)
>     for all connections available out of the box in WKC.